# husky pre-commit yarn/npm test does not react to keybord input

Tags: husky

I have simple app create by create-react-app so my `yarn test` runs `react-scripts test`.
When i run it from console I see standard output

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

And it properly reacts to pressed key. However when i create husky pre-commit hook

```
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn test
```

i see the same output in console, but this time it doesn't react to press. When I press any button it is just printed in console and Im unable to proceed. Any idea how to force husky to properly run Jest tests? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `yarn test` command by default runs in interactive mode to solve this i recommand to add annother command to your `package.json` file like this

```
"scripts": {
...
"test:exit": "react-scripts test --force Exit"
...
}
```

and in husky instead of `yarn test` use `yarn test -- --watchAll=false`